# different colors for different order statuses

Tags: 6, ubercart

Is it possible on store/orders page to use different colors for different order statuses?
This feature can be handy. Or doe's someone know how to implement it?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible Drupal-only solution that can get you there. You're going to need access to your theme css file to add a class for each of your order statuses, ex something like this:

```
.order-status-pending { color: yellow; }
.order-status-closed { color: green; }
.order-status-problem { color: red; }
```

Now go to views and edit the 'orders' view that is added by Ubercart and then select the field for 'order statuses' from the Fields display section. Next, select 'Style Settings', 'customize field HTML', 'Create a CSS class' and then use the tokens to add your custom class there, ex:

```
order-status-[status]
```

You could also rewrite the output of the field using the replacement tokens to something like this:

```
<span class='order-status-[status]'>[status]</span>
```

This won't work on multiple word order statuses, but you could use jquery instead to do this kind of conditional styling, using their much more powerful selectors.

Comment: hi, thank you for reply. Where exactly should I select 'style settings' and 'customize field html'... ? Where can I use the tokens?

Comment: whoops - forgot to add the edit 'orders' view line. Fixing now

Comment: oh:) I apologise. Your advice is for drupal 7. I use drupal 6:)

Comment: are you familiar with drupal views theming? its not that much different from 6.x to 7.x -- if you click the field under the fields section in your orders view you're going to see most of these same options

Comment: Yes I am familiar with themng views. Are you using ubercart views module? I use default admin/store/orders screen. Is it possible to create orders list without additional modules using views? Thank you.

Comment: as far as I know ubercart 2.x for drupal 6 doesn't provide any view to show orders.